# How would I loop over the permutations of N numbers with a given range, preferably without recursion?

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I have *N* numbers, and a range, over which I have to permute the numbers.

For example, if I had 3 numbers and a range of 1-2, I would loop over `1 1 1`, `1 1 2`, `1 2 1`, etc.

Preferably, but not necessarily, how could I do this without recursion?

For general ideas, nested loops don't allow for an arbitrary number of numbers, and recursion is undesireable due to high depth (3 numbers over 1-10 would be over 1,000 calls to the section of code using those numbers)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: You can use Guava's Collections2.permutations method: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.java#L581. If you don't want to use this directly, looking at the implementation may be helpful.

Comment: @kingkupps while this is helpful, I wouldn't like to add libraries to the project this is for. Thank you though.

Comment: Note: do not include the answer in the question. That is not how Stack Overflow works. The answer section is where visitors should look for the answers. I reverted your question to its previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, is to loop with one iteration per permuation, and use the loop variable to calculate the values that a permuation is made off. Consider that the size of the range can be used as a modulo argument to "chop off" a value (digit) that will be one of the values (digits) in the result. Then if you divide the loop variable (well, a copy of it) by the range size, you repeat the above operation to extract another value, ...etc.

Obviously this will only work if the number of results does not exceed the capacity of the `int` type, or whatever type you use for the loop variable.

So here is how that looks:

```
int [][] getResults(int numPositions, int low, int high) {
    int numValues = high - low + 1;
    int numResults = (int) Math.pow(numValues, numPositions);
    int results[][] = new int [numResults][numPositions];
    for (int i = 0; i < numResults; i++) {
        int result[] = results[i];
        int n = i;
        for (int j = numPositions-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            result[j] = low + n % numValues;
            n /= numValues;
        }
    }
    return results; 
}
```

The example you gave in the question would be generated with this call:

```
int results[][] = getResults(3, 1, 2);
```

The results are then:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 1
2 2 2
```

Comment: This helps a lot! Thank you